# Http requests to CEP

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I installed the CEP ( Proton ) through the official documentation, https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_Installation_and_Administration_Guide

After that, I watched  this recommended video to learn more about CEP. https://edu.fiware.org/pluginfile.php/653/mod_resource/content/1/CEP-Tutorial.mp4

But I can't check engine instance state, because appears this error in response:`Could not read instance state, message: Error activating jmx proxy:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that JMX is not properly configured.
As described in the [installation guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_Installation_and_Administration_Guide), in the Apache Tomcat users configuration file you need to add manager-jmx role, and add it to the manager user name:

```
<tomcat-users>
  ...
  <role rolename="manager-jmx" />
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx" /> 
  ...
</tomcat-users>
```

You need to enable JMX access on Apache Tomcat, by adding it to CATALINA_OPTS, as described in the [installation guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_Installation_and_Administration_Guide).

You also need to specify the JMX service port in the ProtonAdmin.properties file, as described in the same [installation guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_IBM_Proactive_Technology_Online_Installation_and_Administration_Guide).